# Upload file to folder under AS S3 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to a folder under a bucket in s3, but I have a problem with the path. Here's an example of code :

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer;

public class S3Uploader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bucketName = "user-bucket";
        String folderName = "user-data";
        String fileName = "user.txt";
        String fileContent = "test data";

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;

        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();

        try {
            PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(folderName + "/" + fileName)
                    .build();

            s3.putObject(request, RequestBody.fromString(fileContent));
            System.out.println("File uploaded successfully to S3!");
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The code shows an error and transforms or encodes "/" to "%2f", how to solve this error ?

Error uploading object: exception while calling s3.PutObject: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/persisted-data/s3/assets/user-bucket/user-data%2fuser.txt@null'

Why it show @null ?

I use localstack with dokcer-compose command!

Comment: Possibly caused by `RequestBody.fromString(fileContent)`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Using your exact code (except for bucket name and an added credentials provider) I'm able to run this fine.  My env is Ubuntu 22.04, Java 21.02, and v2.25.3 of the AWS Java SDK.  Can you change the code to have the exception handler do an `e.printStackTrace()` and update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AWS SDK for Java V2 code works. The only difference that i see is RequestBody.fromFile(new File(objectPath).

```
public class S3Uploader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bucketName = "myjunebucketxxx";
        String objectPath = "C:\\AWS\\AdobePDF.pdf";
        String objectKey = "books/Adobe.pdf";
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
        putS3Object(s3, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath);

    }

    public static void putS3Object(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String objectKey, String objectPath) {
        try {
            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(objectKey)
                .build();

            s3.putObject(putOb, RequestBody.fromFile(new File(objectPath)));
            System.out.println("Successfully placed " + objectKey + " into bucket " + bucketName);

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that my PDF doc is in the correct location:

[image]